# How to export from WINSTAR to ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, import

I have GIS-data in a very old "winstar" type of format.

However, currently I only use ArcGIS for Desktop and QGIS.

Currently, I only have the winstar in a dxf-format. This can be visualized in ArcGIS, but I don't have any attributes in the attribute table.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can import this old-fashioned winstar stuff to ArcGIS for Desktop or QGIS including the underlying attribute table?

Comment: What is Winstar? What kind of format it is? Links to the web pages? Add more details to your question.

Comment: Googling "winstar gis" gets a few hits but there may be more than one product returned so we definitely need you to tell us precisely what the format/product your question involves before it is likely to be answered.  There is an **edit** button beneath your question that you can use to revise it.